# Bitbucket API always returns 400 when trying to create an issue using REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, http-status-code-400, bitbucket-api

I am building nodejs wrapper around Bitbucket REST API , here is the documentation for the REST API for creating issue https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/issues+Resource#issuesResource-POSTanewissue

Every time i try to create the issue the service returns a 400 error which says some mandatory fields are missing , below is my code

```
this.createIssue = function(accountName, repoName, title,callback) {

    var options = {
        rejectUnauthorized: this.strictSSL,
        uri: this.makeUri('/repositories/'+accountName+'/'+repoName+'/issues'),
        method: "POST",
        followAllRedirects: true,
        json: true,
        body:{
            title:title,


        }

    };

    console.log(options.body)

    this.doRequest(options, function(error, response, body) {


        if (error) {
            callback(error, null);
            return;
        }

        if (response.statusCode === 404) {
            callback('Version does not exist or the currently authenticated user does not have permission to view it');
            return;
        }

        if (response.statusCode === 403) {
            callback('The currently authenticated user does not have permission to edit the version');
            return;
        }

        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            callback(response.statusCode + ': Unable to connect to JIRA during createVersion.');
            return;
        }


        callback(null,body)


    });
};
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong,or what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem, it was the encoding which was causing the problem, once I set it to proper one, it actually started working. Changed the parameter form "form" to "body"

working code

this.createIssue = function(accountName, repoName, title,callback) {

```
var options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: this.strictSSL,
    uri: this.makeUri('/repositories/'+accountName+'/'+repoName+'/issues'),
    method: "POST",
    followAllRedirects: true,
    json: true,
    form:{
        title:title,


    }

};

console.log(options.body)

this.doRequest(options, function(error, response, body) {


    if (error) {
        callback(error, null);
        return;
    }

    if (response.statusCode === 404) {
        callback('Version does not exist or the currently authenticated user does not have permission to view it');
        return;
    }

    if (response.statusCode === 403) {
        callback('The currently authenticated user does not have permission to edit the version');
        return;
    }

    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        callback(response.statusCode + ': Unable to connect to JIRA during createVersion.');
        return;
    }


    callback(null,body)


});
```

};